Does the WSO2 identity Server 7.0.0 support profile linking for users between two tenants
I need to know whether this is practical use case that can implement from the WSO2 identity server that link two profiles that are in the two tenants.
I check the documentation, it doesn't mentioned whether that is possible, or not.
